# Laravel sort model by one to many relationship

Tags: laravel, search, eloquent

I have two models `Location` and `Danger`

`Danger` has two fields `location_id` and `user_id` it simply save users report about locations

btw `Danger` has a one to many relation with `Location`

**the question is**

how can I sort locations with count of it's danger in a search form

here is my form:

```
$locations = Location::latest();

    if ($request->get('q')) {
        $q = $request->get('q');
        $locations->where('desc', 'like', '%' . $q . '%')
            ->orWhere('name', 'like', '%' . $q . '%');
    }

$locations=$locations->paginate(12);

return view('list')->with(compact('locations'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `location` has many `danger` and your relation is named dangers then you can use [`withCount()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models) for sorting as:

```
$locations = Location::withCount('dangers');

if ($request->get('q')) {
  $q = $request->get('q');
  $locations->where('desc', 'like', '%' . $q . '%')
      ->orWhere('name', 'like', '%' . $q . '%');
}

$locations->orderBy('dangers_count', 'desc')

$locations=$locations->paginate(12);
```

Answer (score 1):

this might work.

```
$locations = Location::latest();

    if ($request->get('q')) {
        $q = $request->get('q');
        $locations->where('desc', 'like', '%' . $q . '%')
            ->orWhere('name', 'like', '%' . $q . '%');
        $locations->sortBy(function($item, $key){
            return $location->danger()->count();
        })
    }

$locations=$locations->paginate(12);

return view('list')->with(compact('locations'));
```